# Не могу найти xvfb на винду

Tags: windows, golang, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Пытаюсь раскурить Selenium, использую для работы с ним Golang. Как полагается нашел либу "github.com/tebeka/selenium", скачал chromedriver, selenium-server. Но вылазит ошибка: "Error starting frame buffer: exec: "Xvfb": executable file not found in %PATH% exit status 1". Соответственно его надо скачать, но если на линуксе sudo apt-get xvfb, то на синде я не смог найти как и где. Вопрос сосбвенно в том что делать, где скачать?

Comment: Но зачем он вам, если все основные браузеры поддерживают headless-режим и без всяких xvfb?

Comment: Это во-первых, а во-вторых xvfb всё равно бесполезен в винде, потому что Windows-приложения не используют X11 и не смогут использовать xvfb

Comment: @andreymal вероятно автор скопипастил код реализации с unix систем, и не разбираясь пытается использовать его под win))))